# SSH within SSH displays the wrong machine name in the xterm title bar

Tags: ssh, xterm, window-title

I am working on a distributed system connecting to several servers at once. Nothing is started manually in the program I am working on, but this is how to recreate the error manually.

I start a xterm then I SSH to a machine like this:

`ssh machine_1`

In there I start another xterm in the first xterm like this:

`xterm &`

Then the title bar of the new xterm window is something like "username (on machine_1)"

In this xterm I SSH to another machine like this:

`ssh machine_2`

But then the title bar remains like this: "username (on machine_1)"

even though I am logged on to machine_2. I want it to say "username (on machine_2)". Completely removing the parenthesis would also be fine.

I tried xtermset but that does not affect the parenthesis.

Comment: I am not sure how your "(on machine_1)" is getting added to the xterm titlebar. Is there anything like this in your .bashrc or .bash_profile on machine_1? If xtermset doesn't remove it, it's possible this is a feature of your X server, saying where _the xterm_ comes from rather than the ssh session, and you will need to start a new xterm on machine_2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either xterm or the shell on machine_1 is configured to set the terminal title to contain the machine name. Configure your shell on machine_2 to set the terminal title to contain the machine name. You'll also want to make sure that the shell on machine_1 resets the title when the ssh session is terminated. The usual way to do this is to make the shell reset the terminal title whenever it displays a prompt. This has the added benefit of resetting the terminal title to something sensible if a full-screen text mode application sets it while it's running.

You can set the title of an xterm by displaying the [escape sequence](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#ctlseqs_ms) `\e]2;my title here\a` where `\e` is an escape character (`\033`) and `\a` is a bell character (`\007`). Include this sequence in your shell prompt. For [bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Printing-a-Prompt), put a line like this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1="\[\033]2;xterm on $HOSTNAME\a\]$PS1";;
```

The backslash-bracket punctuation `\[…\]` tell bash that what is inside has a width of 0 (if you leave off the brackets, the display will be garbled).

For more a fancy title that changes after each command, you can include variable and command substitutions in the prompt string if you set the `promptvars` option.

In zsh, set the title from the [`precmd` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions), which is executed before each prompt.

```
precmd () {
  print -n "\e]2;xterm on $HOSTNAME in $PWD\a"
}
```

While you're at it, you can set the title from `preexec` to contain the name of the running command. Here's a simple way which doesn't react very well to unprintable characters in the command:

```
preexec () {
  print -nr $'\e]2;'"xterm on $HOSTNAME running $2"$'\a'
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that is was a problematic setting with the machine_1 and machine_2 in question that caused the parenthesis to appear.